# What does this notation do in multi-meter?

Tags: multimeter

What does this red marked area do in this multimeter?
**UT33B Palm-Size Multimeter

Model: TOL-00032**

[image: Multimeter]

Comment: Do you have the manual?

Comment: VtC because questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design and the answer can be easily found in the user manual or internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those three are battery test modes for different voltages. It differs from the DC voltage range by placing a small load on the battery.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The battery measurement function puts a resistance to load the battery with about 50 mA while doing the measurement.